# How to use Python to read a binary file with NULL characters

Tags: python, parsing, utf-8

I am trying to read a database's binary file and parse it using python. Never done anything like this with python and am having some trouble with "messy" data. There are a bunch of NULL values in the data and I'm not sure how to read files byte by byte without checking for NULL terminator.

How can I read this file with all of these messy values in it?

I was using this method to get a variable number of bytes from an open file buffer (I don't know if that is the right name for it, but I would have already called `file =  open(file_path, "rb")` before calling this function on file.

```
    def getBytes(self, file, numBytes):

      bArray = file.read(numBytes)
      x=0
      while x < numBytes:

        if (bArray[x] < 32) or (bArray[x] > 126):
          bArray[x] = 32
        x+=1

      charArray = bArray.decode("utf-8")

      self.buffer += numBytes

      return charArray
```

I'm also getting this error even when only testing a string of uft-8 characters with no special characters. So this is definitely not a great implementation.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\git\pgdump_parser\src\python\PG_Dump_Parser\Source_Code\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    Sp = Parser.Parser("./PG_Dump_Parser/Data/small_data.txt")
  File "D:\projects\git\pgdump_parser\src\python\PG_Dump_Parser\Source_Code\Parser.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.inData = self.getEntities()
  File "D:\projects\git\pgdump_parser\src\python\PG_Dump_Parser\Source_Code\Parser.py", line 66, in getEntities
    found = self.findNextCREATE(file)
  File "D:\projects\git\pgdump_parser\src\python\PG_Dump_Parser\Source_Code\Parser.py", line 34, in findNextCREATE
    byte = self.getBytes(file, 1)
  File "D:\projects\git\pgdump_parser\src\python\PG_Dump_Parser\Source_Code\Parser.py", line 97, in getBytes
    print("bArrayOld: %s \nx: %s" % (bArray[x], x))
IndexError: bytearray index out of range`

Comment: There is a mismatch between the code and the traceback; the code never calls `print` like the error message reports.

Comment: Why are your trying to limit binary bytes from a binary file to ASCII and why do you care for UTF-8 here? What is the reason for not simply using: `def getBytes(self, file, numBytes): self.buffer += numBytes 
      bArray = file.read(numBytes)

      return bArray` Code cannot be correctly formatted in a comment but it should be enough for you to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace certain characters with spaces, it is easier to use the `translate` method.

(Note that `self.buffer` should be updated with the number of bytes you *actually* read, not the number of bytes you *tried* to read.)

```
not_printable_ascii = bytes(range(32)) + bytes(range(127, 256))
spaces = b' ' * len(non_printable_ascii)
trans_table = bytes.maketrans(not_printable_ascii, spaces)

def getBytes(self, file, numBytes):
    bArray = file.read(numBytes)
    self.buffer += len(bArray)
    return bArray.translate(trans_table).decode("utf-8")
```